# How do core electrons factor into the $f$-sum rule?

Tags: condensed-matter, correlation-functions

Kubo gives in [Statistical-Mechanical Theory of Irreversible Processes](https://doi.org/10.1143/JPSJ.12.570) section 8 the sum rules for conductivity,
$$
\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} d \omega \operatorname{Re}\left(\sigma_{\mu \nu}(\omega)\right)=\frac{n e^{2}}{m} \delta_{\mu \nu}=-\lim _{\omega \rightarrow \infty} \operatorname{Im}\left(\omega \sigma_{\mu \nu}(\omega)\right)\:.
$$
Since the density response function is related to the conductivity, the same sort of sum rule can also be derived for the density response function. Mazenko in Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics chapter 3 derives the analogous expression with operator identities,
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} d \omega \operatorname{Im}(\chi(k, \omega))=k^{2} \frac{n e^{2}}{m}\:.
$$

Now, my intuition dictates that the core electrons should not contribute to conductivity. For example, the conductivity of copper should be based entirely around its one outermost electron; the $1s$ electron for example should not be relevant. However, for example in Mazenko's derivation, the factor of $n$ is obtained as the thermal average of the number density operator $n(x)$, which makes no distinction between conduction and core electrons.

How is this resolved? I find it very difficult to believe that the core electrons are playing a role here, but the density operator makes no distinction between conduction and core electrons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are talking about the "optical conductivity" $\sigma(\omega)$. This is a quantity that is defined at all frequencies from dc to infinity. The value $\sigma(0)$ is the dc conductivity of a material. In a simple (Drude) metal, this value is $n e^2 \tau / m$, where $n$ is the conduction electrons density (you outermost electrons); $\tau$ is the average scattering time and $e$ and $m$ the electronic charge and (effective) mass.

However, when you go to high frequencies (infrared, visible, UV, x-rays, etc) the optical conductivity is no longer measuring the dc inverse resistivity. It measures the conductivity at those high frequencies. It is related to the absorption coefficient of the material and it is dominated by interband optical transitions, hence bringing core electrons to play. If you go to high enough energies all the electrons will be taken into account.

As a side note, the sum rule is experimentally very useful as it measures the total number of electrons. Therefore it is a constant independent of external parameters such as temperature or pressure and it does not change across phase transitions. (Provided that you can get as close to infinity as possible).